# Do you bundle your library for user to import, or let them import the source?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

You write libraries using ES6/7, so someone importing the source would have to use Webpack + Babel to transpile the code.

You can get around that problem by providing the transpiled bundle. But then the problem is you would bundle in your dependencies, which the user may also have. Then the dependency gets bundled in redundantly for the user.

You want to preserve the

```
import MyLib from 'my-lib'
```

syntax so you don't want to provide two import paths.

What do you do?

Comment: The first thing is that it is opinion-based question. The second thing is that there's a lot of reasons why it should be available in transpiled form and there's not so many of them why untranspiled form is necessary (though it never hurts to include `src` into package).

Comment: Not sure how this is opinion-based. Redundantly bundling modules is a deal-breaker in front-end and I doubt people would argue on this. But if that problem is solvable then suddenly providing the bundle is better. @estus

Comment: You're explicitly asking for personal opinions. If this isn't the definition of opinion-based question, it's pretty close, and it is something that is not encouraged on SO. You can doubt, but people won't thank you for forcing them to use Babel just to use your library. It really depends on the case what the bundle should look like. I don't see much sense in asking personal opinions, but if you will take a look at existing libraries, you may notice that UMD bundle + CJS ES5 is pretty much standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, I found an excellent example:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Redux uses package.json prepublish to transpile the source code, without bundling it. This works perfectly as it no longer requires the user of the library to use babel, and at the same time does not bundle in dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should just bundle your library. Even if the user happens to use the same dependencies that you use, most likely they will be using a different version, which might not work with your library.

If you want to reduce the size of your bundle, you should use [Rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/)—it uses tree-shaking, which basically means that your bundle will include only the parts of the code that you actually need.

Comment: Well, suppose that I bundle in library A version 1.0.2 (^1.0.0 in package.json), while the user is using 1.0.3 with specification ^1.0.0 in package.json. Then wouldn't a npm install followed by Webpack compilation be able to eliminate the redundancy in the "provide source not bundle" way?